# Is there any possible way to read client hardware configuration (microprocessor,ram,hdd etc) from server side through network?

Tags: client-server, firewall-access

I wanted to read client side hardware configurations like RAM,Microprocessor,HDD etc from a server...And I couldnt find anything. Is there any way to get it

Comment: Well I think the best that can be achieved would anyway request a client software to be installed...

Answer (score 0):

AIDA64, SiSoft Sandra, etc.  I believe those programs would work.  Kali Linux if you want a challenge.